# is there a mapping from HTML property names to DOM propety names?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

in HTML

```
<td colspan=3 style='background-color:pink;' >hello world</td>
```

but in Javascript / DOM

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.colSpan = 3;
td.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
```

is there a mapping of HTML properties and styles to Javascript/DOM attributes and styles?

understand about camelBack for CSS style

have some HTML specifications, eg, `colspan=3`, and implementing them with Javascript.  so need a mapping between HTML property name and DOM property names.

---

ok, here's a mapping for the abnormal properties.  those with a 1::1 mapping and functions are omitted.

```
html2dom = {
  acceptcharset: 'acceptCharset',
  accesskey: 'accessKey',
  bgcolor: 'bgColor',
  cellindex: 'cellIndex',
  cellpadding: 'cellPadding',
  cellspacing: 'cellSpacing',
  choff: 'chOff',
  class: 'className',
  codebase: 'codeBase',
  codetype: 'codeType',
  colspan: 'colSpan',
  datetime: 'dateTime',
  checked: 'defaultChecked',
  selected: 'defaultSelected',
  value: 'defaultValue',
  frameborder: 'frameBorder',
  httpequiv: 'httpEquiv',
  longdesc: 'longDesc',
  marginheight: 'marginHeight',
  marginwidth: 'marginWidth',
  maxlength: 'maxLength',
  nohref: 'noHref',
  noresize: 'noResize',
  noshade: 'noShade',
  nowrap: 'noWrap',
  readonly: 'readOnly',
  rowindex: 'rowIndex',
  rowspan: 'rowSpan',
  sectionrowindex: 'sectionRowIndex',
  selectedindex: 'selectedIndex',
  tabindex: 'tabIndex',
  tbodies: 'tBodies',
  tfoot: 'tFoot',
  thead: 'tHead',
  url: 'URL',
  usemap: 'useMap',
  valign: 'vAlign',
  valuetype: 'valueType' };
```

Comment: @BoltClock - I believe you but personally have been completely inept in finding one.  can you give me a lead?

Comment: @pst - a [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/idl-definitions.html) wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @pst - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there are any exceptions to the *remove special characters and apply lowerCamelCase* rule when it comes to CSS properties (besides for IE vendor prefixes).

Comment: @JosephSilber - thanks for the link.  but looking for mapping between the HTML and the DOM property names.

Comment: @JosephSilber The exception was for class/className (HTML<->DOM) properties .. I guess that is secondary information, but I got off on a tangent due to the incorrect title.

Comment: @ccyoung - Your best bet would be to log `element.attributes` when you want to access a new property, and examine that.

Comment: @pst Changed title from "attribute" to "property name" - was thinking of `attribute` generically instead of a DOM reserved word

Comment: @ccyoung - Where did you get that list from? It doesn't look correct to me in several respects.

Comment: There is no "defaultvalue" attribute. The "value" attribute maps to the `defaultValue` property. Likewise for "selected" and "checked".

Comment: @Alohci could not find authoritive mapping.  based list on http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/idl-definitions.html and my best guess.  what changes should be made?

Comment: @ccyoung - Well, e.g: "for" -> "htmlFor". But the real problem is that there isn't a simple relationship. For example "class" is reflected by both "className" and "classList" properties. The "charset" attribute isn't reflected at all. The "value" attribute is reflected by the "defaultValue" property on `input`, but the "value" property on `li`. The "value" property on input has a "mapping" to the "value" attribute for initialization purposes but they do not reflect one another. The HTML5 spec has a whole section to describe the relationship between the "form" attribute and the "form" property.

Comment: @Alohci - thanks a lot.  removing problems properties. goal is to take (a subset of HTML) declared properties and render them through javascript.  from what you say a full mapping is impossible.  but the partial mapping, as is here, allows the (limited) practical problem to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DOM IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/idl-definitions.html) exposes different HTML attributes differently for convenience and consistency. That is, `COLSPAN` -> `colSpan` and `CLASS` -> `className`. (Remember that HTML attributes are *not* case-sensitive by virtue of being case-normalized while DOM properties are.)

Since all standard HTML attributes *are* listed in the appropriate DOM IDL - which is the authoritative source - then a mapping can be generated off of the supplied definitions. Other documentation may need to be consulted for vendor-specific or not-yet-codified attributes.

The [1.1.3 Naming Conventions](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-45A944CB) says:

> While it would be nice to have attribute and method names that are short, informative, internally consistent, and familiar to users of similar APIs, the names also should not clash with the names in legacy APIs supported by DOM implementations. Furthermore, both OMG IDL and ECMAScript have significant limitations in their ability to disambiguate names from different namespaces that make it difficult to avoid naming conflicts with short, familiar names. So, DOM names tend to be long and descriptive in order to be unique across all environments.

That is, while the DOM attempts to pair well with HTML (and XML), it favors internal consistency and universal use.

---

The original premise of the question was incorrect because `background-color` *is not* an HTML attribute. It is a CSS property that is exposed in the DOM via `elm.style.backgroundColor` (see Jospehn Siber's answer for the mapping).

Because `background-color` is *not* an HTML attribute it *cannot* be compared with HTML attributes such as `colspan` or `class`.

Comment: cool.  using link to gen names.  really surprised that these property mappings are not more readily available (or at least more easily found)!  will post mapping to question

Answer (score 2):

You just have to camel-case the properties. [Here's how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L518):

```
function camelCase (prop) {
    return prop.replace(/-([a-z])/gi, function (all, letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Then you could just call this function:

```
camelCase('background-color') // backgroundColor
```

Or directly in your code:

```
td.style[ camelCase('background-color') ] = 'pink';
```

---

HTML property names [generally follow this same pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/idl-definitions.html), but there are a few exceptions. Your best bet would be to just check it in the browser itself. Whenever you have a new property name that you want to use, just call the following on that element:

```
console.log( element.attributes );
```

and you'll get all the property names that are available for that element.

Comment: right, that works with style, but does not handle properties like `colspan` vs `colSpan`