# Iterating through CSS styles - style naming inconsistency

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to iterate through CSS styles. For example I get a style like this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[10].style
```

That returns a `CSSStyleRule` which is an object with both integer and string keys.

The integer and `.length` keys can be used to iterate through the property assignments in the style, and each one gives the name of the property, for example:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[10].style[0] == "max-height"
```

The string keys give access to the actual actual text for the style like this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[10].style["maxHeight"] == "100px"
```

So in theory it is easy to iterate through all the properties. But notice the maddening change from `max-height` to `maxHeight`! How can I deal with this? How do I even know what this mapping is? Do I just have to write a function that converts every `-a` to `A` and so on?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531737/javascript-incapable-of-getting-elements-max-height-via-element-style-maxheight

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Well it's not really a duplicate because those are about getting a specific style, whereas this is about iterating through the styles. However the answer to my question was found in the answer to Bhojendra's linked question.

Comment: This can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544497/104380

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this function to change the case:

```
function camelCaseCssName(str) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '-') {
            if (i < str.length - 1) {
                ret += str[i+1].toUpperCase();
                ++i;
            }
        } else {
            ret += str[i];
        }           
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The link Bhojendra posted also contains this version which I haven't tested, but it is a lot shorter:

```
styleProp = styleProp.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
  return letter.toUpperCase();
});
```