# How do I remove a DOM element property?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have an element with the property `className` set to "test", how do I remove the HTML attribute associated with that property?

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
const set = (el, prop, value) => el[prop] = value;
const rm  = (el, prop)        => delete el[prop]; // How do I do this?

const el = document.createElement("div");

set(el, "className", "test"); // el: <div class="test"></div>
rm (el, "className");         // el: <div></div>
```

Do I have to map properties to attributes and use `removeAttribute()`? If so, is there a mapping provided by the DOM that I can use? Or do I have to write my own?

Or is there something like `delete el.className` that I can use?

Same question for other attributes such as `onclick`, `htmlFor`, etc.

Example:

```js
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "test";

// How do I unset className?
delete el.className; // Doesn't do anything.
el.className = null; // Sets the string "null". Same for "undefined".

// Do I need to do this?
// If so, can I get this from somewhere in the DOM?
const propToAttrMap = { "className": "class", "htmlFor": "for", ... };
el.removeAttribute(propToAttrMap["className"]);
```

Comment: Try defining your question as a set of inputs and the desired result. Show an example of this _function_ signature.

Comment: Right, I think I see what you're asking now. You're setting **properties** which may correspond to setting **attributes** and you're wanting to undo that. I'd say the real challenge here is that not all properties relate to attributes and vice versa

Comment: @Phil, that's right (I'm talking about removing an HTML attribute associated with a particular property). That's OK if there is no association between a property and an attribute. But if there is, I'd like to remove it. The idea is that if I can **set** `className`, then I'd like to **unset** it as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a mapping from HTML property names to DOM propety names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14544481/283366) (holding off on the dupe hammer until you can confirm)

Comment: @Phil, I've seen that question a few times. It asks if there's a mapping, and the answer is that there isn't. I was wondering if there's another way. I don't necessarily want to use `removeAttribute()` and I don't necessarily want to map properties to attributes. What I want is to unset that value, which may not require mapping.

Comment: @Phil, but if there's no way to unset it once it's set, then I suppose mapping it will have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the property to an empty string. It doesn't necessarily remove the attribute but should nullify it. For Boolean types like `disabled` it should work similarly.

The one caveat I can think of is that once an element has been given an attribute, it **will** appear under query selectors it would have been absent from previously.

```js
const set = (el, prop, value) => el[prop] = value;
const rm  = (el, prop)        => el[prop] = "";

const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const div = document.querySelector("div")

console.log("original:", div.innerHTML)
console.log("classy elements:",
  document.querySelectorAll("[class]").length)

set(btn, "className", "red")
set(btn, "disabled", true)
console.log("set both:", div.innerHTML)

rm(btn, "className")
console.log("rm className:", div.innerHTML)

rm(btn, "disabled")
console.log("rm disabled:", div.innerHTML)
console.log("classy elements:",
  document.querySelectorAll("[class]").length)
```

```html
<div><button>Click me!</button></div>
```

Comment: I was considering this but I thought it's not the prettiest result. Still, if there's no other way, then it sure beats mapping. Looks like setting DOM properties is a one way street! Once you set it, it's **set**. Thank you.

Comment: @rid seems so. I'm not sure what you intend to achieve with the removal but keep in mind that your elements _will_ appear under different query selectors. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Oh, indeed, you'll still be able to find them something like `[class]` or `[disabled]`.

Comment: @rid the Boolean attributes do seem to be removed. String ones hang around though

Comment: Ah, nice, at least there's that. There's a lot more string than boolean ones though. I haven't thought of the selector issue, thank you for pointing it out. Seems a bit unsafe for something like library code. I'll unfortunately probably have to consider mapping because of this.

Comment: @rid yep, seems like the way to go. Hard to maintain though

Answer (score 1):

`class` is your attribute & in order to remove any attribute, you just need to write:

```
el.removeAttribute('your_attribute')
```

In your case:

```
el.removeAttribute('class')
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to remove a class and how to remove an attribute. The problem is that I'm writing a function in which I don't have the attribute, I only have the `Element` property and I need to remove the appropriate attribute based on the property with which it's associated. Added this as part of the question.

Comment: @rid you wanna remove an object/array item? Your question says two different things

Comment: No. Please see the example of what I'd like to achieve that I posted in the question.

Comment: @ZainShabir there's some more clarity in the question comments too

Comment: @rid You are trying to create your own functions like `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`, am i right?

Comment: DOM elements have a property called `className`. If you set that property, then the attribute `class` gets set to whatever you set that property to. What I want is to unset the `class` attribute by using the `className` property.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to say that I'd like to create my own `setProperty()` and `removeProperty()` functions.

Comment: @rid You can't use `delete` keyword to remove any attribute, plus you can't remove/unset attribute using `className`.

Answer (score 0):

While jQuery provides an extra method(addProp() and removeProp()) for setting and getting element property values,
Yes there's no such big thing in plain JavaScript. Element properties, such as href, title, alt, and value, are directly accessible as JavaScript object properties.

Find below one example.

```
var el = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(el.href);
if (el.title != 'Welcome') el.title = 'Welcome';

var inp = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
console.log(inp.value);
inp.value = 'Hello World!';
```

Even you can add and delete new property to a DOM element as shown below.

```
var el = document.querySelector('div');
el.animal= { name: 'Lion'};
console.log(el.animal);
delete el.foo;
```

Thanks